# Cannot deploy Laravel App to Heroku - symfony/polyfill-ctype v1.24.0 requires php >=7.1

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I'm currently developing an app in Laravel and deploying it in Heroku.

I get this error when pushing:

> symfony / polyfill-ctype v1.24.0 requires php >= 7.1

Anyone knows how to solve this?

The truth is that I investigated but I couldn't think of what to do. I already tried running `composer update` and there is no solution either.

Im using `Laravel Framework 8.78.1`

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.40",
    "laravel/passport": "^10.2",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5"
},
```

Comment: What is unclear about the error message?

Comment: I'm also getting this error with my app and when I followed these directions from Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel.

Comment: @miken32 I don't know if it's a concept problem that I don't understand, but according to my composer file, the app requires a php version of at least 7.3; and the polyfill-ctype resource requires> = 7.1!
That's what I don't understand ! haha

Comment: @Johann can you do a `php -v` inside heroku and make sure what exact version do you have?

Comment: @matiaslauriti PHP 8.0.13 (cli) (built: Nov 18 2021 15:45:57) ( NTS )

Comment: @Johann can you share the full log or at least who is requesting `symfony/polyfill-ctype`?

Comment: @matiaslauriti I don't know if you mean the log when I try to deploy, here it is:
https://www.codepile.net/pile/KN72rDx4

And as for who requires 'symfony / polyfill-ctype' I honestly have no idea, it's a pretty big project and I wouldn't know how to find out.

PS: I already tried to change the stack from heroku to 'heroku-20 stack' and it didn't work either.

Comment: @Johann I have no idea about heroku. Do you have a local environment like a Docker? Do you have in your local environment the same PHP version? Where you able to `composer install` in your environment? I also see you are using `composer 1` instead of `composer 2`, but I am not sure if that could be an issue or not, I would recommend upgrading it. I have no idea how do you install `composer` on heroku, but if you are compiling the image that heroku uses, just do `composer self-update` before anything.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: If `php -v` says you're running 8, then `composer` must be looking at a wrong version. What does `head -n 1 $(which composer)` say? How does this compare to `which php`? No clue how this Heroku works though, probably worth reading this article: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to the require section of your composer.json file:

```json
"symfony/polyfill-ctype": "~1.23.0",
"symfony/polyfill-iconv": "~1.23.0",
"symfony/polyfill-mbstring": "~1.23.1",
"symfony/polyfill-php80": "~1.23.1"
```

From Heroku support:
"As symfony/polyfill-ctype declares ext-ctype as provided since v1.24.0 and this package is already bundled with the PHP package that Heroku provides, this leads to a conflict due to how Composer 1 resolves dependencies."

The 1.23 packages don't have this issue. Don't update to 1.24 until Heroku supports composer v2.

**UPDATE Jan. 7, 2022:** Heroku has hotfixed the issue. Declaring specific package versions should not be necessary. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/issues/528

Comment: VERY VERY THANKSSSS YOU! its work! haha